# Tkinter - text widget distorting column sizes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the grid manager and have two frames side by side, and five columns with 1 button in each below the two frames in a second row, evenly spaced. All use "sticky" NSEW since I want them to scale proportionally if I enlarge the window.

When I add a text entry widget to the right frame, it distorts the buttons below them so they are larger than those to the left. I can't figure out how to prevent this distortion, or put another way, how to keep each column the same size.

Is there a reason why the text entry widget is not respective the row/col/weighting? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `columnspan` or `rowspan`. This *should* allow the buttons to be unaffected by the text widget.

for example:

```
root=Tk()
button1=Button(root,text="button1")
button1.grid(row=1,column=0)
textbox=Text(root)
textbox.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In each frame you should set the "propagate" status to false, this will keep the frame from resizing based on what is inside.  So if the frame uses `grid()` set `grid_propagate(False)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the fact you've given the entry widget a specific width (or are accepting the default). Since the widget wants to be a particular size, it will cause the column to grow in order to fit the requested size of its children.

One solution is to set the size of the entry widget to 1. Then, because of the sticky settings for E and W, it will expand to exactly fit the column.