# Buttons differently sized in equally weighted grid manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why is it that these buttons are not the same size when using equal weights in the grid?

```
class Screen(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        f = tk.Frame(self)
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        f.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        f.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        f.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

        l1 = tk.Label(f, text='Text')
        l1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

        l2 = tk.Label(f, text='Text', anchor='w')
        l2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='sw')

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(f)
        self.e1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.b1 = tk.Button(f, text='B1')
        self.b1.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='nsew')

        l3 = tk.Label(f, text='Text', anchor='w')
        l3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='sw')

        self.e2 = tk.Entry(f)
        self.e2.grid(row=4, column=0, ipady=2, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.b2 = tk.Button(f, text='B2')
        self.b2.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.b3 = tk.Button(f, text='B3')
        self.b3.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky='nsew', command=self.test)

        self.update_idletasks()
        self.geometry(f'500x{self.winfo_reqheight()}')
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def test(self):
        a = self.b1.winfo_width()
        b = self.b2.winfo_width()
        c = self.b3.winfo_width()
        print(a, b, c)
```

Output: `111 110 111`

The Buttons `B1` and `B3` are in Column 3 of the grid and `B2` is in Column 2. The only way to ensure they are all the same size is if I set their `width` configuration to something like `width=10`.

Desired layout:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                             L1                          |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|      L2      |            |              |              |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|                     E1                   |      B1      |
+--------------+------------+ -------------+--------------+
|      L3      |            |              |              |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|                     E2                   |              |
+--------------+------------+ -------------+--------------+
|              |            |      B2      |      B3      |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Tried to make the columns as close to even scale as possible. But the layout is a grid of 5 rows and 4 columns. The top label `L1` would span all columns in the first row. The two entry widgets `E1` and `E2` would span the first 3 columns in their respective rows. For some reason, `B2` is receiving less size.

**Edit:** Best I can determine is that the `Entry`  widget causes weighted issues, but I do not know why. The same topic is answered by Bryan Oakley [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473405/8371266) but I am confused as to why a default width on a widget doesn't become overwritten by the weight keyword of the grid manager.

Comment: Grid's `weight=` option controls how to distribute *excess* space to columns (and rows).  To force equal size to columns, you want to use `uniform=` instead.

Comment: @jasonharper I do not see any documentaton for that keyword

Comment: @datta documentation for tkinter sometimes is incomplet and you may have to read in [Tcl/Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm)

Comment: @jasonharper Please see the edited hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Why is it that these buttons are not the same size when using equal weights in the grid?

**It's only weighted, not calculated**. It depends on used widgets and columnspans.
You are using `sticky='nsew'` overall, change to `sticky='ew'` if you don't want to grow to `sn`.

---

One possible option is, to use different `weight=` values, to give the Grid Manager a hint, which widget you want to be **more weighted**, e.g:

```
            f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            f.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            f.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
            f.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=4)
```

---

Another option is, to use `.grid_columnconfigure(c, minsize=<minsize>)`.
This forces the Grid Manager to obey a `minsize=` for a column.

> **Source**: `tkinter.__init__: def grid_columnconfigure(...`
>   Valid resources are:
>
> - minsize (minimum size of the column),
> - weight (how much does additional space propagate to this column)
> - pad (how much space to let additionally)

But the results are also not predictable, at best at fixed window size.

---

To get it work on window resizing, bind the `<Configure>` event to the `Frame` and
set the same **calculated** `minsize=` for every column.

[image] [image]

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        f = tk.Frame(self)
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        f.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

        ...

    def on_configure(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        columns = w.grid_size()[0]
        minsize = w.winfo_width() // columns

        for c in range(columns):
            w.grid_columnconfigure(c, minsize=minsize)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***